# SCSS mixin adding zero in front of time duration on transition

Tags: sass

I have a Sass mixin that I am using for all my transition effects:

```
$transition-time: .2s;
$transition-method: ease-in-out;

@mixin transition($transition-property){
    -webkit-transition: $transition-method $transition-property $transition-time !important;
    -moz-transition: $transition-method $transition-property $transition-time !important;
    -ms-transition: $transition-method $transition-property $transition-time !important;
    -o-transition: $transition-method $transition-property $transition-time !important;
    transition: $transition-method $transition-property $transition-time !important;
}
```

If you notice how my `$transition-time: .2s;` is declared as .2s. The problem is that Sass is adding a zero in front `0.2s` when it is compiled. I never thought that this would be a problem, but it is making a couple of my transitions not work. I have tried to put `.2s` within the mixin, but it still adds the zero when it is compiled. Anyone else have this issue and know how to resolve it?

Comment: Do you have a demo of this not working?

Comment: @cimmanon Unfortunately, I do not have a live version available. I am working on the site locally.

Comment: You can't create a small demo showing that `0.2s` does not work, but `.2s` does?  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @cimmanon I can create it on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=FMdcAgDaLN However, it does not replicate the problem that I am having. It appears to be an anomaly as it is not working only on a couple of items.